# Android's query suggestion

Tags: android, algorithm, autocomplete

Does anyone know what algorithm Google uses in query suggestions for android (the feature of autocomplete that retrieves text from database or an array when you start typing)?

I'm really interested in knowing the used algorithm to achieve that, and I couldn't yet find information about it from anywhere!

Thanks

Comment: do you mean android keyboard autocomplete?

Comment: no, it's like the use of AutoCompleteTextView ..! it shows you a drop-down-list-like dialog with potential queries similar to the one you start typing. Many algorithms provide this feature, like Edit distance, N-gram, soundex, etc. but I want to know what google is using :)